# Google App Engine 302 status Task Queues in production only

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, laravel-4, google-tasks-api

I'm receiving a 302 response for Task Queues on Google App Engine (Standard), only in production. My local environment processes them fine. (dev_appserver.py) I'm running Laravel 4.2.

I've created a queue.yaml file and deployed that as well

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 3
```

My route for tasks looks like

```
Route::post('tasks', array('as' => 'tasks', function(){
    return Queue::marshal();
}));
```

Log

```
2018-08-31 12:30:09.256 EDT
POST
302
1,003 B
407 ms
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
/tasks
```

Comment: What is the URL of the very next log entry (the one redirected to)?  Check to see if the URL redirects to one with a trailing slash.  By chance, do you have any rerouter going from http: to https:?

Comment: That’s exactly it. I found i couldn’t force ssl on that route. Thank you for taking the time to help. You’re spot on.

Comment: I guess I should make this an answer then, for posterity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any rerouter script redirecting `http://` requests to `https://`.  If you do, consider filtering for taskqueue requests, such as (Python/Flask logic shown. Modify to suit your language):

```
if not 'AppEngine-Google' in request.environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'fake'):
```